# a command to build something when enough resources are available

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a queue-able command to tell a structure to "build/research this when enough resources are available"?

Comment: Requesting info about the downvote.

Comment: Someone didn't like your question, that is all. There is a lot of discussion on Meta about downvoting etiquette, but as of now there are no rules about explanation and no reason for voters to deanonymise themselves. Maybe someone thought that your question is too obvious, and you didn't do enough research yourself before asking. Or they dislike people trying to cheat the game, or whatever.

Comment: There is a command: Keep hitting the keyboard shortcut to build something and when the "we require more minerals" voice stop, you can build it ;) lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

That is part of the very strategy that goes into multiplayer matches.

It would break the foundations of the game if you could queue build orders without having the resources.

One could simply queue up an entire list of building and units as well as movements and not even partake in actually managing their resources or using micro.

Comment: I think there's a strong argument to be made that "micro," while certainly skill-based and definitely important in SC, is not "strategy."

Comment: @Amadeus9 Strategy is just the set of choices one makes based on information in order to get the best possible outcome. If your opponent is busy building up an army, it's most certainly strategy to use micro by any number of 'cheese' methods to hurt their workers or other key buildings.

Comment: As a comment, this is actually possible in Warcraft 3. You could queue up build commands and it would use resources as normal, but if you queued beyond what you could afford, it would still place an outline of the building but in red and not take any resources. If the worker tried to build it and you still didn't have the resources it would move on, but would build it and take the resources if you did.